# Why the set $g^{-1}(\{0\}) $ is not a differentiable manifold?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$. Then I am triying to figure out why this function is not a differentiable manifold , **I was trying to give an explicit coordinate system, but I can't figure out how.**

Then I tried to use the result that says the following: Let $A \subset \mathbb{R} $ open, $p<n$, $g:A \to \mathbb{R}^p$ of class $C^1$ such that $g'(x)$ has rank $p$ for all $x \in A$ such that $g(x)=0$ therefore $g^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a differentiable manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n-p$.

So I computed the Jacobian matrix and it gives me the following: $(2x \;\; -2y )$ and it has rank 1 so I don't know what is the problem with this manifold. Can someone help me to find where is the property that does not hold please? Thanks a lot.

Definition: A subset $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a differentiable manifold of dimension $k$ if, for each $x \in M$, exists open sets $U \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a class $C^1$ function $f:U \to V$ such that:

1) $x \in V$

2) $f(U)=V \cap M$, $f$ is an homeomorfism

3) for each $y \in U$ the jacobian matrix has rank k

Comment: The problem occurs at $x = y = 0$.  Note that this space is just the graph $\{(x,y): y = \pm x\}\subset \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: This set is not even a topological manifold. Removing $(0, 0)$ leaves $4$ connected components.

Comment: Ok, so which is the condition that does not hold?

Comment: Well watching this in the perspective of the system of coordinates.

Comment: $(2x, -2y)$ has rank 1... except at $(0,0)$, where it has rank 0.

Comment: Ok, but it not suffices to say that right? I have to do the coordinate system and then see what is the part that does not hold

Comment: @user162343: If you want an answer pointing to a specific part of a particular formal definition you have in front of you, you need to put that definition in front of _us_ too. Otherwise we can't know how its parts are arranged and in which order.

Comment: Right, let me post it, I am sorry I should have known better that I am sorry :)

Comment: READY :), so what do you think?

Comment: The conditions fail at $x=(0,0)$. It's easy enough to make (1) hold, but you can't make (2) hold, not even with a $\mathcal C^0$ function.

Comment: Ok can you explain more about the latter please?

Answer (score 1):

This is an elaboration of Ayman’s comment above. The set $ {g^{\leftarrow}}[\{ 0 \}] $ is simply
$$
\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^{2} \mid y = \pm x \}.
$$
This is not a topological submanifold of $ \Bbb{R}^{2} $. Assume the contrary. Then $ (0,0) $ would possess an open neighborhood in $ {g^{\leftarrow}}[\{ 0 \}] $ that is homeomorphic to an open ball in $ \Bbb{R}^{n} $ for some $ n \in \{ 1,2 \} $. We can rule out $ n = 2 $ because the removal of any point in an open ball does not take away its connectivity, but removing $ (0,0) $ from $ {g^{\leftarrow}}[\{ 0 \}] $ produces four distinct connected components. We can also rule out $ n = 1 $ because the removal of any point in an open interval yields exactly two connected components, not four. We therefore have a contradiction.

**Note:** We do not consider $ n \geq 3 $ due to Invariance of Domain. We also do not consider $ n = 0 $ because $ {g^{\leftarrow}}[\{ 0 \}] $ is not discrete.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the thing is that we haven't seen a topological manifold and even topology :(

Answer (score 1):

Property 2. fails at the origin. If $V$ is an arbitrary neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$, there does not exist an open set in the real numbers and a smooth map $f:U \to V$ whose derivative has rank one everywhere and whose image is $M = V \cap g^{-1}(0)$.

Intuitive reasons are given in the comments. One approach is, $g^{-1}(0)$ is the union of the lines $y = x$ and $y = -x$. By hypothesis, some number $t_{0}$ maps to the origin, i.e., $f(t_{0}) = (0, 0)$. If $f$ were a homeomorphism from $U$ to $M = V \cap g^{-1}(0)$, then $f$ would induce a homeomorphism from $U \setminus\{t_{0}\}$ to $M \setminus\{(0, 0)\}$. But the former has precisely two connected components and the latter has at least four.

Comment: thanks a lot, and formally reasons are..., what is a former?

Comment: Modulo the statements about numbers of connected components, this is a rigorous proof. :) Is the issue that you haven't proven theorems about "connected sets", "path components", or the like? For example, do you have the tools to prove that the formula $h(t) = (\ln|t|, \operatorname{sgn}(t)\ln|t|)$ defines a homeomorphism from $\mathbf{R}\setminus\{-1, 0, 1\}$ to the union of the lines $y = \pm x$ with the origin removed? (Here, $\operatorname{sgn}(t) = t/|t|$ is the signum function, defined on the set of non-zero real numbers.)

Comment: No, I only have the result and the definition as in my post :(

Comment: I see.... It may be best to consult your instructor, then. It's possible they just want you to think intuitively about the impossibility of tracing an X in the plane if you aren't permitted to lift your pencil or backtrack along a path you've traced.

Comment: Well the other thing I have is that when we have two system of coordinates then then we have a difeomorfism :), Can this help?

Comment: Can you post that intuitively thinking please?

Comment: Well...a curve $C$ diffeomorphic to a real interval can be drawn by putting down your pencil and tracing $C$ without stopping or retracing. Try doing this with an "X". (Separately, I just saw your question about the term "former". When two things are compared or mentioned in sequence, the first is sometimes called "the former" and the second is called "the latter". :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but,  is this the only thing I have to argue , or how can you put that intuition formally with the results I saw? THANKS :)

Comment: Another idea: The level set $g^{-1}(0)$ has two linearly independent tangent directions at $(0, 0)$; if you can prove that a set diffeomorphic to an interval doesn't have this property (which should be straightforward, depending on your definition of a diffeomorphism), you can get a rigorous proof with your available tools.

Comment: Ok, let me try, if I get stuck, can I ask you for help?